# Nexus 7 spinner in action bar bug

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I am having a problem when running my application on Nexus 7 tablet while it works on other devices even the nexus 4.

I tried to put a spinner populated by elements from JSON response (I get this response from the server via Asynctask) and it all works wonderfully except on Nexus 7 because the app just breaks on start (probably while setting adapter on spinner), unfortunately I can't debug the app on Nexus 7 because I don't have access to administrator account. While debugging the same problem on Nexus 4 I found out that my spinner in action bar was not being found by findById() method al thou same code worked on Galaxy S2 and after changing the menu item to this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuCategory"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_categories"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/collection"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menuCategorySpinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

It started working on Nexus 4 but still breaks on Nexus 7. Relevant part of the code I think is:

```
//First do this to initialise elements of the menu
invalidateOptionsMenu();
//Find the spinner by id
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.menuCategorySpinner);
//Initilise adapter
final ArrayAdapter<Category> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, result);
//Set adapter
spinner.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

I think the problem is in the last line since the spinner could be null if it was not found by id earlier but I don't know why it is not being found only on Nexus 7, does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Please check to make sure that you don't have more than one definition for R.id.menuCategorySpinner in your app.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, that did happened to me sometimes with the names of elements but it's not the case here. By the way I think I found a solution and will add it in the edit if someone else stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution but still hate the fact that there are discrepancies like this on devices in different android versions since (Galaxy S2 is using 4.1.2 and Nexus devices are 4.2.2). I am even considering reporting this as bug on android platform but will have to check if it is valid as a bug report. All in all here is an answer for those who need it:
In your onCreateOptionsMenu just add:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.full, menu);
            //getActionView() get a view for the given action
    spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menuCategory).getActionView();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

getActionView() is the important part it is quite logical but what I don't get is why on other platforms  spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menuCategory); works so if someone comes across this question and can explain that part please write a comment